# Change an OpenGL context's size

Tags: c, windows, winapi, opengl

All of the tutorials show you how to create an OpenGL context to cover the whole space of the window.

With a tree view for example, you can do this:

```
HWND treeViewHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_TREEVIEW, 0, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 192, rc.bottom, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

To create a tree view that takes up a portion of the screen, (192 width).

But with OpenGL I can't seem to create a context that goes from 192,0 to the bottom right of the application window. Here's the code:

```
HWND openGLHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "openGLHwnd", 0, CS_OWNDC | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 192, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, hwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

HDC hdc;
HGLRC hrc;

PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
int format;

hdc = GetDC(openGLHwnd);

memset(&pfd, '\0', sizeof(pfd));
pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
pfd.nVersion = 1;
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 24;
pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
format = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
SetPixelFormat(hdc, format, &pfd);

hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
if(hrc == NULL) return 0;
if(wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc) == FALSE) return 0;

glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glViewport(0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom);
gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)rc.right / (GLfloat)rc.bottom, 0.1f, 1024.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

SwapBuffers(hdc);

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
ShowWindow(openGLHwnd, SW_SHOW);

UpdateWindow(hwnd);
UpdateWindow(openGLHwnd);
```

Nothing shows up in the space, though there should be a red box since that is what I set my clear color to.

Comment: When you understand what a Device Context handle really is in Win32, you will understand why this does not make much sense. It is a handle to a drawable surface (to borrow D3D / modern Windows DWM terminology) defined by a window's client region (by default). The surface is automatically resized when you resize the window it is associated with, there is no getting around this. You do have a sort of hacky way around this, which is to use `GetDCEx (...)` and define a clip region that is a portion of the client rectangle. However, the better solution would simply be to re-define the viewport.

Comment: Note that when I say "window", I am not limiting the discussion to application windows. Anything with an HWND has a DC associated with it, so you can create a child window that is a portion of your application's window and use the DC for this if you want; this is how drawing into OpenGL controls/widgets works in frameworks like MFC, Qt, etc.

Comment: I made a small edit to my post. I hope it is clearer now, the space where the OpenGL window should be (0,192 to the bottom right of the application window) does not contain anything, though it should be black, no?

Comment: Not necessarily, you have not shown anything being drawn in this code listing. In fact, you have not even cleared the color buffer. You just swapped buffers, which by all accounts have undefined contents to begin with - probably leftover garbage from another window.

Comment: I edited my code further to change the order of some things and also added glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); so there should be a red box, but alas, nothing shows up.

Comment: Two things come to mind after looking through my own codebase. I always use a window class style: `CS_OWNDC` for child-window OpenGL contexts and I use the window styles: `WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`. I do not see either one of these things in your code. By the way, could you delete a few of your one-line status update comments? This is getting really cluttered and I do not want to move this into chat just yet, because I think this last comment will fix your problem.

Comment: Still not showing up, further updated the code but I'm not sure if I'm putting the CS_OWNDC in the right place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That here is in the wrong order:

> ```
> glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
>
> SwapBuffers(hdc);
>
> ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
> ShowWindow(openGLHwnd, SW_SHOW);
>
> UpdateWindow(hwnd);
> UpdateWindow(openGLHwnd);
> ```

When you make those OpenGL calls the Window is not visible, i.e. it has no framebuffer space to draw on available, so all your drawing calls go into nirvana. Also the `UpdateWindow` calls tell Windows, that the contents of the Window are dirty, that Windows should discard their contents and send a WM_PAINT event the next full redraw iteration loop of Windows.

The correct order would be to show the windows before making any OpenGL drawing calls. ***But** you should not do **any** drawing calls at all in the window creation code.*

Also your `glViewport` call parameters don't match the size of your window. It's larger in the width direction by 192 pixels. Not a problem, because the viewport only defines the coordinate mapping. But it's definitely not what you probably intended.

Last but not least, make sure that the class style for your OpenGL window has the `CS_OWNDC` flag set. BTW: Where do you create the Window Class for your OpenGL window? I don't see the code for that.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so we can only get so far with comments. Time to sit down and write a draft answer...

The second parameter to `CreateWindowEx (...)` is the name of a window class, which I actually have not seen you create anywhere in your code. To do this, you need to make a call like this:

```
WNDCLASS wc;

wc.style         = CS_OWNDC;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = GlobalWndProc; // No idea what you call this in your app
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
wc.hInstance     = GetModuleHandle (NULL);
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon        (NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
wc.hCursor       = NULL;
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (BLACK_BRUSH);
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = "openGLHwnd";

RegisterClass (&wc);
```

As it stands right now, `CreateWindowEx (...)` ought to be failing because you are attempting to assign it a window class name that has never been registered.

After this is done, you can call:

```
HWND openGLHwnd = CreateWindowEx (WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "openGLHwnd", 0,
                                  (WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD |
                                   WS_VISIBLE),
                                  192,       0,
                                  rc.right,  rc.bottom,
                                  hwnd,      NULL,
                                  hInstance, NULL);
```